Packaging Electron Desktop Application
When I package my electron application, this error has come.
errorOut=ERROR: Cannot create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : C:\Users\HIRAN\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\104702627\darwin\10.12\lib\libcrypto.dylib
ERROR: Cannot create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : C:\Users\HIRAN\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\104702627\darwin\10.12\lib\libssl.dylib
I was changed the package.json file as this. but the error still comes.
"win": {
"target": "nsis",
"asar": false
},

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/8149#issuecomment-2066845811 sounds like it's already covers this?

When I recloned a repo I was previously working on, and running electron-builder I was getting this error with the context of 7zip trying to unzip files coming from some external resources.
I created a PowerShell instance with Admin privileges, which allowed 7zip to modify contents.
